# Opening terminal window in a specific folder in mac os x

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

Does anyone know the easy way of opening the terminal window in a specific path, it is so annoying to keep changing the path as needed very frequently during development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open terminal here in Mac OS finder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag the folder from Finder onto Terminal's dock icon. Use "New Tab" (Cmd+T) from within Terminal if you need another session with the same current folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this little application:
https://github.com/nmadhok/OpenInTerminal

You can select finder sidebar items, select file/folders to open the directory in Terminal. This is a really handy tool if you're a developer on Mac.