# Is there any way to right click inside a folder and open a terminal there on a Mac? (Like the one in ubuntu)

Tags: macos, terminal, menu, right-click

[google drive and other program added functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttsa3.png)

I think that if google drive and the other program to create text files did that, there should be a way to do the same and add the open in terminal functionality.

[open in terminal ubuntu functionality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH2d2.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate of ["How can I open a Terminal window directly from my current Finder location?"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location) on Apple.SE, and the closed SO question ["Open terminal here in Mac OS finder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open terminal here in Mac OS finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/420456/open-terminal-here-in-mac-os-finder)

Comment: Those are solutions, but I want the same one that is present in Ubuntu, because I have to switch between ubuntu and os x very often. And, everytime I want to open a new terminal on my mac I try to do it like in Ubuntu.. So, it would be very nice if i could do it the same way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. While in the finder navigate to the folder where you want to open a terminal. Open that folder and right click. One of the options is to open a terminal.

If you want to use iterm there is a 3rd party app named [Go2Shell](https://zipzapmac.com/Go2Shell) which puts an icon on your finder window. Clicking on the icon opens a terminal window in whatever directory you're currently in. You can set Go2Shell to use iTerm.

Comment: I've seen that kind of solutions in related posts. But, I want the same one that is present in Ubuntu, because I have to switch between Ubuntu and os x very often. And, every time I want to open a new terminal on my mac I try to do it like in Ubuntu... So, it would be very nice if I could do it the same way.

Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 7):

> System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services

Enable **New Terminal at Folder**

Right click or ctrl-click any folder and you can now choose **New Terminal at Folder** from the menu.

Comment: this is not for current folder, this for folder inside current folder!

Comment: @user25 True, but its fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this little Finder Toolbar application: https://github.com/Ji4n1ng/OpenInTerminal

It looks more like macOS Toolbar style.